# Причина - прозаичная или прозаическая?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Причина - прозаичная или прозаическая? Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А хороший вопрос, спасибо.

ПРОЗАИЧЕСКИЙ, -ая, -ое.
1. 
к Проза (1 зн.). П. перевод " Слова о полку Игореве". П-ое произведение. П-ие жанры (например, комедийный, жанр записок и дневников и т.п.).
2.
Будничный, обыденный; непоэтичный. П-ое выражение. Задача самая п-ая - рассчитаться с долгами. П. разговор. П-ие отношения. Говорить о самых прозаических вещах. Приятель мой - человек п.
(неинтересный, приземлённый). 
3.
Деловой, практический. Преследовать п-ие цели. < Прозаически, нареч. (2-3 зн.). П. мыслить.

ПРОЗАИЧНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно.
=Прозаический (2-3 зн.). П-ие интересы. Хоть вы и молоды, но весьма прозаичны. <  Прозаично, нареч. Выражаясь п. Прозаичность, -и; ж.

(БТС Кузнецова)

Понятно, что речь идет о втором значении слова "прозаический". Но в этом значении "прозаический" эквивалентно "прозаичный". Таки образом оба варианта следует признавать правильными.

Однако насколько могу судить, по сложившейся практике вариант "прозаическая причина" употребляется много чаще, поэтому я рискну рекомендовать именно его. Если, конечно, у автора нет веских причин для иного.

Answer (score 1):

Прозаичный - Будничный, ограниченный мелкими житейскими интересами
Прозаический - 1. Соотносящийся по знач. с сущ.: проза, связанный с ним. 
2. Свойственный прозе (1), характерный для нее. // перен. Связанный с повседневной, бытовой, материальной стороной жизни; скучный, будничный, обыденный, лишенный поэтичности.
Действительно, зн-ие слова "прозаичный" совпадает с переносным зн-ем слова "прозаический"